# How to enable .htaccess authentication on Debian / Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

My `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "protected area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Gives error 500

In my Apache log I get:

> configuration error:  couldn't check user.  Check your authn provider

I guess it is not enabled : how to enable that on Apache 2.2 with Debian?

Comment: Just to clarify, you get that error as soon as you try to navigate to the relevant directory? You don't get a password prompt? Do you have the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive set in your server config (needs minimum `AllowOverride AuthConfig`)? Otherwise, the necessary modules should be enabled by default. (?)